# Python --version shows different version to VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, interpreter

When i run `python --version` in the terminal of vs code, it outputs `Python 3.8.8`, even though my settings are

```
"workbench.colorTheme": "GitHub Dark Default",
"workbench.startupEditor": "none",
"window.zoomLevel": 1,
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/local/bin/python3.11",
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": []
```

and vs code 'Selected Python Interpreter' is 3.11.0 64-bit.

I want to know how to make it so the same python is running, as have been having issues with modules saying theyre not installed when they are etc. and modules not running etc.

[Many python interpreters image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vBhe.png) I also seem to have a lot of python interpreters, and im not sure how to get rid of them

Comment: VSCode doesn't use `python` command, it refers directly to the specific interpreter by the full path. If you run any script in VSCode you will notice that it says `/usr/local/bin/python3.11 script.py`, not `python script.py`. If you want your `python` command to refer to the same 3.11 interpreter, remove path to 3.8 from PATH environment variable.

Comment: @matszwecja how would i go about removing it, just delete the folder...?

Comment: No, I am referring to the PATH variable - [How To View and Update the Linux PATH Environment Variable](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-view-and-update-the-linux-path-environment-variable#step-1-mdash-viewing-the-path-variable) (although just removing the folder with 3.8 should work too, if you don't need it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The **Select Interpreters** panel detects and displays all python versions available on the machine, including virtual environments. If you think you have too many environments, just uninstall the python version you don't want.
- You use the `python --version` command in the terminal, the output result has nothing to do with the settings in your *settings.json*, it depends on the python settings in the environment variable ***path*** in your computer.
- The role of `"python.defaultInterpreterPath"` in *settings.json* is:

  when you open a new workspace, if you do not manually select an interpreter, it will use this default interpreter as the python interpreter in the workspace.
- You need to select the **correct** interpretation as the python interpreter in the **Select Interpreters** panel, and then use `Run python File` to execute the script

  [image]

*https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_working-with-python-interpreters*